# Getting "read failed after 0 of 4096 at xxxxxx: Input/output error" error for LVM

Tags: 12.04, boot, kernel, lvm

I have system with Ubuntu 12.04.
On this system used **[LVM](http://www.howtoforge.com/linux_lvm)** for managing disk drives and similar mass-storage devices.
When I used *`lvscan`* command for scanning all the logical volumes then it displayed following output

```
(12.10_20140228_00)ubuntu@pdc-00000:~$ sudo lvscan
[sudo] password for ubuntu: 
  /dev/ubuntu/rootfs_12.10_20140228_01: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 10737352704: Input/output error
  /dev/ubuntu/rootfs_12.10_20140228_01: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 10737410048: Input/output error
  /dev/ubuntu/rootfs_12.10_20140228_01: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 0: Input/output error
  /dev/ubuntu/rootfs_12.10_20140228_01: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 4096: Input/output error
  /dev/ubuntu/rootfs_12.10_20140409_00: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 10737352704: Input/output error
  /dev/ubuntu/rootfs_12.10_20140409_00: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 10737410048: Input/output error
  /dev/ubuntu/rootfs_12.10_20140409_00: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 0: Input/output error
  /dev/ubuntu/rootfs_12.10_20140409_00: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 4096: Input/output error
  ACTIVE            '/dev/ubuntu/videos' [30.00 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/ubuntu/swap' [5.59 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE   Original '/dev/ubuntu/rootfs_12.10_base' [10.00 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/ubuntu/logging' [12.00 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/ubuntu/bluetooth' [12.00 MiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/ubuntu/machine_config' [12.00 MiB] inherit
  ACTIVE   Snapshot '/dev/ubuntu/rootfs_12.10_20140228_00' [6.00 GiB] inherit
  inactive Snapshot '/dev/ubuntu/rootfs_12.10_20140228_01' [6.00 GiB] inherit
  inactive Snapshot '/dev/ubuntu/rootfs_12.10_20140409_00' [6.00 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE   Snapshot '/dev/ubuntu/rootfs_12.10_20140409_01' [6.00 GiB] inherit
```

Also here is the output of `pvscan`

```
(12.10_20140228_00)ubuntu@pdc-00000:~$ sudo pvscan
[sudo] password for ubuntu: 
  /dev/ubuntu/rootfs_12.10_20140228_01: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 10737352704: Input/output error
  /dev/ubuntu/rootfs_12.10_20140228_01: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 10737410048: Input/output error
  /dev/ubuntu/rootfs_12.10_20140228_01: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 0: Input/output error
  /dev/ubuntu/rootfs_12.10_20140228_01: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 4096: Input/output error
  /dev/ubuntu/rootfs_12.10_20140409_00: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 10737352704: Input/output error
  /dev/ubuntu/rootfs_12.10_20140409_00: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 10737410048: Input/output error
  /dev/ubuntu/rootfs_12.10_20140409_00: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 0: Input/output error
  /dev/ubuntu/rootfs_12.10_20140409_00: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 4096: Input/output error
  PV /dev/sda2   VG ubuntu   lvm2 [101.79 GiB / 20.18 GiB free]
  Total: 1 [101.79 GiB] / in use: 1 [101.79 GiB] / in no VG: 0 [0   ]
```

What is meaning of `/dev/ubuntu/rootfs_12.10_20140228_01: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 10737352704: Input/output error`.

Please let me know why this error is getting and is it affect on the system?

Comment: You appear to have been playing around with lvm snapshots and have several of them that are broken.  Remove them with `lvremove`.

Comment: I exactly have this problem and there are important data on lvm disk which i need them. How can i access them? or How can i use that LVM disk agane?

Comment: @shgnInc: did you solve it? If you are on a hoster, you could go into rescue mode of the server and mount those disks you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically I got this error because of the two broken snapshots.

```
inactive Snapshot '/dev/ubuntu/rootfs_12.10_20140228_01' [6.00 GiB] inherit
inactive Snapshot '/dev/ubuntu/rootfs_12.10_20140409_00' [6.00 GiB] inherit
```

To fix this issue I removed the broken snapshots using `lvremove` command.

```
sudo lvremove /dev/ubuntu/rootfs_12.10_20140228_01
```

For this I referred [this](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/lvremove.8.html) post.

Comment: can you [edit] and provide a bit more detail for those who are unfamiliar with how to use the `lvremove` command? That would likely get this answer out of the low quality queue.